# How to scroll only a second div with no height specified

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML page with 2 divs. The first one I need it to contain an image with 100% width and auto height (so that it keeps the aspect ratio).
The second one contains a list. 
I want to scroll only the list and keep the image visible.
This is [the fiddle that I tried.](https://jsfiddle.net/u5xwta4b/) But nothing seems to work. 
I really think there is a simple solution but my CSS skillz are at beginner level. I tried `style="/* overflow: auto; */position: relative;/* height: 100%; */` but no luck

LE: I want the list to begin AFTER the image - so the scroll will start somewhere after the image

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/xy8q8h16/ ?

Comment: Not really, I want the list to start AFTER the image.

Answer (score 5):

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) does this well ([where supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)):

```css
html,body,#wrapper {height: 100%; margin:0;}
body {overflow: hidden;}
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#header {flex: 0 0 auto;}
#header img {width:100%}
#content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
        <img src="http://rockstartemplate.com/blogheaders/bannerdesign2.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div id="content">    
        <ul><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li></ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Chris Coyier's [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) may prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the position attribute for your image to position: fixed;
It should work like this

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a fixed height value to the second div and set `overflow-y: auto`

https://jsfiddle.net/1a440uLa/2/

Comment: The scroll bar is for the whole page, but I need it to start only after the image

Comment: This means that the start of his list is beneath the fixed image though.

Comment: You have to have a fixed height on the second div to do this, check the updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Here: https://jsfiddle.net/p3aw8xu0/

You have to use `position: fixed` to make the div sticked to some part of page and not scrolling.

Alternatively you should probably use your image as `background-image`.

Comment: Not really, I want the list to start AFTER the image.